# ReactJS - Can inline style take state/props as full style string?

Tags: reactjs

**A standard html inline style:**

```
<div style="background-color:blue, height:500px; width:500px;">Foo</div>
```

**I would like to accomplish this in react:**

```
this.state = {
      specialDiv : 'backgroundColor:"blue", height: 500, width:500'
}
```

**And in the html:**

```
<div style={{ this.state.specialDiv }}>Foo</div>
```

It doesn't work, but can something similar, short of using classes be possible, to make style completely dynamic?

> **( I am thinking about how to allow the user to choose his own dynamic styles on the fly and classes won't accomplish that.)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you change to `this.state = { specialDiv : {'backgroundColor:"blue", height: 500, width:500' }}` (notice extra curly brackets), then maybe it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` property takes an object; that object should have CSS properties as the keys, and the values of those properties as the values. So:

```js
// note: you should only ever set `this.state` directly when using
// ES6 classes, and even then only in the constructor
this.state = {
  specialDiv: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    height: 500,
    width: 500
  }
};

// ...

// `this.state.specialDiv` is already an object,
// no need to wrap it in extra curlies
<div style={this.state.specialDiv}>Foo</div>
```